# Having some trouble with XMLHTTPRequest.send() in Safari, Chrome, and Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome, xmlhttprequest

I have some javascript code that will make a request to an api. And the request spits out xml as the response. I am using XMLHTTPRequest to get the xml.

In Firebug I notice it just fails, and throws an exception. I am not really sure what going on. Here's a demo in Firebug you'll notice in the console window that it will fail.

Here's the code I run,

```
xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlHttp.open( "GET", configgg, false );
xmlHttp.send()
```

When I was searching for clues online to whats going, there was a topic about issues when requesting stuff from another domain won't work and the issue is server side. If that's the case how would I turn that on(allowing other domains to make xmlhttprequests)? The API is on one of our servers but we are making request tests from other domains to get it to work.

Comment: If you use google chrome for debugging you would have seen this error: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.internetvideoarchive.com/Video/TitleSearch.aspx?DeveloperId=a92e6bd5-f9d0-4e03-91c4-3019c5614da4&OutputFormat=1&SearchTerm=Jaws. Origin http://elvis.rowan.edu is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: @gnur is there a way to allow all domains access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the other answers the fact that you are trying to access something from another domain is the cause of the script failing.

To fix this you could circumvent the javascript limitation by loading a local PHP script that echo's the contents of the API url.

Comment: A Local php script on elvis.rowan.edu? If so, is there any other way, I know Flash uses a crossdomain.xml, does Javascript have anything similar?

Comment: It turns out that we will be hosting the file, and the php thing worked and help with the sample test. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[Same_origin_policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) does not allow you to make calls across domain. You can look into [CORS](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2009/07/cross-site-xmlhttprequest-with-cors/) in you are working with new browsers or you need to use a proxy or you need to start using [JSONP](http://remysharp.com/2007/10/08/what-is-jsonp/).

Setting up the browser's security to allow cross domain calls is asking for trouble if the user surfs the web with it.

Comment: the browsers I plan to work with are all HTML5 ready browsers. So hopefully they should be new enough. I will look into CORS.

Answer (score 1):

The answer everyone here will love will involve the Same Origin Policy, which disallows cross-domain calls.  But I've been through something similar and I know that's not the answer you're looking for.

I know how to do this in Internet Explorer using an MSXML ServerXMLHTTP object, but as far as trying it in other browsers, try doing this:

```
xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();  
xmlHttp.open( "GET", configgg, false );  
xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Host", configgg);
xmlHttp.send();
```

Comment: Thanks @user535617 but no luck in Chrome and Firefox

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason it's failing is because when you're using the `send` method, but not including any arguments, you have to tell it `null`, like so:

```
xmlHttp.send(null);
```

This happens with some other methods, as well (`getComputedStyle` also fails if you don't include `null` as the second argument).

Comment: send() doesn't require any parameters. On most browsers it works without null as well, so this isn't the problem here.

Answer (score 0):

```
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open('GET','baselead.xml',false);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
    xmlhttp.send('');
```

you have to use 'baselead.xml' qoute('') it works for me in chrome